# Optical Flow: What exactly is the temporal derivative?

Tags: computer-vision, derivative, opticalflow, temporal

I'm trying to understand what the **meaning** of a temporal derivative is in an image. While I understand the brightness constancy equation, I don't understand why taking the difference between two images gives me the temporal derivative.

Taking the difference between two frames gives me the difference in pixel intensity per pixel between the two, but how is that the same as asking how much the image changed over a certain span of time?

Answer (score 3):

The temporal derivative `dI/dt` of the image `I(x,y,t)` is the rate of change of the image *over time* at a particular position. As you noted, this is the difference in pixel intensity between the two frames. Considering a single pixel at `(x,y)`, the finite difference approximation to the derivative is

`f_d = ( I(x,y,t+delta) - I(x,y,t) ) / delta` so that `f_d -> dI/dt` as `delta -> 0`.

In this case `delta` is simply set to one. So we are approximating the image derivative (with respect to time) by the difference between adjacent frames.

---

One aspect that may be confusing is how that relates to the movement of objects *in* the image. If you have some physics background, for instance, you might think about the difference between [Eulerian and Lagrangian frames of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_and_Eulerian_specification_of_the_flow_field): in the more intuitive *Lagrangian* viewpoint, you consider an object moving by tracking it over the pixels (space) in which it moves, e.g. watching a cat as it hops over a fence. The *Eulerian* view, which is closer to what we do in optical flow, is to track *what happens at a single pixel*, and never take our eyes off of it. As the cat passes over that area of (pixel) space, the pixel's values will change, and then go back to "normal" when it's gone.

These two views are in some sense equivalent, but may be useful in difference situations. In computer vision, tracking an object is *hard*, while computing these Eulerian-like temporal derivatives is *easy*. Ideally, we could track the cat: consider a point `p(t)=(x_p(t),y_p(t))` on say its head, then compute `dp/dt` and figure out `p(t)` for all `t`, and use that for downstream processing. Unfortunately, this is hard, so instead we hope that brightness constancy is usually locally true, and use the optical flow to estimate `dp/dt`. Of course, `dI/dt` often does *not* correspond well to `dp/dt` (this is why the brightness constancy is an assumption). For instance, consider a light moving around a stationary sphere: `dI/dt` will be large, but `dp/dt` will be zero.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between subsequent frames is the [finite difference approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) to the temporal derivative.

Proper units would be obtained if the value were divided by the time between frames (i.e. multiplied by the frames per second value).